# expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have this class:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

namespace Ispit
{
    template <class T>
    class Value
    {
        template <class Y>
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Value<Y>&) noexcept;
        public:
            Value() noexcept;
            Value(T val) noexcept; //{ podatak = val;}
            Value& operator()();
            bool operator<(const Value&);
            virtual void print(std::ostream&) const noexcept;
            virtual ~Value();
        protected:
            T podatak;
    };

    template <class T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Value<T>& val) noexcept
    {
        val.print(out);
        return out;
    }

    template <class T>
    Value<T>::Value() noexcept : podatak(T()) {}

    template <class T>
    Value<T>::Value(T val) noexcept //: podatak(T) {}
    {
        podatak = T; // this where the error occurs
    }

    template <class T>
    Value<T>& Value<T>::operator()()
    {
        return podatak;
    }
}
```

When compiled gives this error:

```
expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

I've tried adding the template word in various places, but haven't found the rules for variables (not sure if this is a thig).

Doesn't work even if the function is inline...

Compiler gcc 5.2.1

Comment: You're assigning a *type* `T` to the member variable `podatak` Try `podatak  = val` (or better still, move it to the member initializer list `: podatak(val)`).

Comment: @WhozCraig I can't believe I've done this -_-

Comment: Not sleeping is not a valid shield against downvoting. Instead of wasting our time with silly antics, get some sleep before trying once more to solve your problem. Before posting.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Don't answer questions in the comments section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a type to a variable:

```
template <class T>
Value<T>::Value(T val) noexcept 
{
    podatak = T; 
}
```

This should be:

```
template <class T>
Value<T>::Value(T val) noexcept 
{
    podatak = val; 
}
```

or better yet, use the member initialization list:

```
template <class T>
Value<T>::Value(T val) noexcept : podatak(val) {}
```

In addition, you could remove your default constructor and combine it with your 1 argument constructor:

```
//  Remove this code
//    template <class T>
//    Value<T>::Value() noexcept : podatak(T()) {}

// Combine the above into this
    template <class T>
    Value<T>::Value(T val = T()) noexcept : podatak(val) {}
```

The above will default contruct the `T` type if no argument is given, basically combining your original default constructor into the 1 argument constructor.

Comment: The combined constructors will fail for a move-only `T`.